# Windows Form DataGridView not getting DataSet

Tags: c#, winforms

What is wrong with my code?

```
dataSet = new DataSet();
dataTable = dataSet.Tables.Add("Items");

dataTable.Columns.Add("Site", typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add("ItemID", typeof(UInt64));
dataTable.Columns.Add("ItemName", typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add("ListedPrice", typeof(decimal));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Currency", typeof(string));
dataTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dataTable.Columns["ItemID"] };

string site = "mysite";
UInt64 itemId = 44322;
string itemName = "werwer";
decimal listedPrice = 345345;
string currency = "USD";

dataTable.Rows.Add(site, itemId ,itemName, listedPrice, currency);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["Items"];
```

When I run it, it does not enter the row to the GridView, simply adding a blank line

**EDIT** 
I found the problem, it was because I manually created the cells in VS IDE.
How can I still work with the IDE because I want to fix the layout not by code

Comment: Have you tried to use a `BindingSource` as `DataSource` for the grid and the table as `DataSource` for the `BindingSource`? You could also try to call `dataTable.AcceptChanges();`.

Comment: When I checked MSDN for Add method on the DataRowCollection (returned by Rows Property), it accepts either a DataRow or Object array. May be you should create the DataRow object and then add it to the Rows collection or try a similar approach described (here)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wwak56(v=vs.110).aspx]

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. The problem is some where else. You need to find it. I did a small Testing with the above code. Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once..

```
 DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
 DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables.Add("Items");

 dataTable.Columns.Add("Site", typeof(string));
 dataTable.Columns.Add("ItemID", typeof(UInt64));
 dataTable.Columns.Add("ItemName", typeof(string));
 dataTable.Columns.Add("ListedPrice", typeof(decimal));
 dataTable.Columns.Add("Currency", typeof(string));
 dataTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dataTable.Columns["ItemID"]

 dataTable.Rows.Add("mysite",44322,"werwer", 345345,"USD");


 dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["Items"]
```